# Atlas V booster appearance change in flight

Tags: launch-vehicle, booster, atlas-v

In the livestream of the latest Atlas V 541 flight launching the GOES-T satelite I saw that the nosecones of the two visible boosters changed the appearance within a few seconds in the flight.

Is this just some ice that has fallen onto them or somthing else?

[image: Normal appearance(T+ 1:21)]

[image: T+ 1:27]

[image: Shortly before separation (T+ 1:58)]

Comment: For anyone who wanted to watch the video, you can find it here: https://youtu.be/T3w3AoTFP90?t=2303

Comment: The angle with respect to the Sun changes, but it looks more like something (ice?) is forming or changing in some way. Seems to be around max-Q.

Comment: I'd suspect the SRBs just getting hot enough to melt ice at 9-10 miles altitude according to the announcer.

Comment: Why would an SRB nose collect ice? Is it conductive cold from the first stage body?

Comment: It could be recession of the nose cone material due to heating.